# Converting a string of length 20 into a float of length 20

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some strings with numbers inside like '0.9999965341102361' and '3.465889763814134E-6'. I know how to convert them to a float value; however, when I do, they become 9.99996534e-01 and 3.46588976e-06. How can I preserve the full length of the number while still converting to a float? In other words, I don't want to have to round off the original number. Is there a way to do this - can I set the float length equal to 20 or something?

It's been a while since I actually took python in school, so I may be forgetting something rather obvious.

Thank you.

Comment: These numbers don't get rounded for me on Python 3.5

Comment: Python's `float` type stores 15 or 16 significant decimal digits. If you want more than that, check the `decimal` module which can handle arbitrarily many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the decimal module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> 
>>> a = decimal.Decimal('0.9999965341102361')
>>> b = decimal.Decimal('3.465889763814134E-6')
>>> a
Decimal('0.9999965341102361')
>>> b
Decimal('0.000003465889763814134')
>>> a*10
Decimal('9.9999653411023610')
>>> b*10
Decimal('0.000034658897638141340')
>>> print(a)
0.9999965341102361
>>> print(b)
0.000003465889763814134
>>> print('{:1.20e}'.format(b))
3.46588976381413400000e-6
>>>
```

---

decimal.Decimal objects in a numpy array

```
>>> import decimal
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = decimal.Decimal('0.9999965341102361')
>>> y = decimal.Decimal('3.465889763814134E-6')
>>> z = decimal.Decimal('1.23456789012345678901e-2')
>>>
>>> a = np.array((x, y, z))
>>> a
array([Decimal('0.9999965341102361'), Decimal('0.000003465889763814134'),
       Decimal('0.0123456789012345678901')], dtype=object)
>>>
>>> b = np.float64((x,y,z))
>>> b
array([  9.99996534e-01,   3.46588976e-06,   1.23456789e-02])
>>> b[2], a[2]
>>>
(0.012345678901234568, Decimal('0.0123456789012345678901'))
>>>
>>> a*2
array([Decimal('1.9999930682204722'), Decimal('0.000006931779527628268'),
       Decimal('0.0246913578024691357802')], dtype=object)
>>> b*2
array([  1.99999307e+00,   6.93177953e-06,   2.46913578e-02])
>>>
>>> a*b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    a*b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float'
>>>
```

Looks like a numpy array of type object will hold decimal.Decimal objects.  Depending on what you want to do they might work.

Comment: @A.W. - What type of array are you asking about?  decimal.Decimal objects can be put in containers - like [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-you-make-an-array-in-python).  You can put anything in a container/list/array .

Comment: I'm using the NumPy array system.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get better than your machine float, which is 64 bit or 32 bit. My linux laptop has 64 bit words, and the number is preserved:

```
In [6]: f = float('0.9999965341102361')

In [7]: f
Out[7]: 0.9999965341102361

In [8]: f2 = float('3.465889763814134E-6')

In [9]: f2
Out[9]: 3.465889763814134e-06
```